# Joining 2 variables under loop

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu

I'm trying to join 2 variables under loop but I cant get it to work..

My script lists newly added movies. I'm trying to make an output in excel that is clickable. Long story short, I need the script to list the 2 variables like this:

```
ab  
ab
```

Right now it's doing this

```
a  
a  
b  
b
```

This is the code

```
   NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST=''
    for i in $(seq 1 ${NEW_MOVIES_COUNT}); do
        MOVIE_PATH=$(echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_LIST}" | sed -n "${i}p")
        NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST+="$(dirname "${MOVIE_PATH}")/\n"
    done

    LINKNAME=$(echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" | sed -r 's,FOLTERS_TO_BE_SCANNED/HDD-EXTENDED.-SD./,,g')
    NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST=$(echo -e "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" | sed '/^$/d')

 NEW_MOVIES_COUNT=$(echo "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}" | wc -l)

    NEW_MOVIES_LIST=''
    for ((i = 0; i < ${NEW_MOVIES_COUNT}; i++))
        do echo ${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}${LINKNAME}
    done

    echo "Found ${NEW_MOVIES_COUNT} movies and ${NEW_SERIALS_COUNT} serials!"

    ${NEW_MOVIES_LIST}
```

The 2 variables are `NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST` and `LINKNAME`, I can't join them when I run it. Any idea why?

Comment: My bad, corrected ,its producing wrong output

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a newline to the end of the string in the `sed`.  So strip the newline before you display it.

```
newline=$'\n'
echo "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST//$newline//}$LINKNAME"
```

Comment: This ? It won't run unfortunately. I ran it through cron and it's not producing any output  

   NEW_MOVIES_LIST=''
    for ((i = 0; i < ${NEW_MOVIES_COUNT}; i++))
 newlinw=$'\n'
        do echo ${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST}${LINKNAME}
    done

Comment: Corrected, but it's still not giving me any output NEW_MOVIES_LIST=''
for ((i = 0; i < ${NEW_MOVIES_COUNT}; i++))
        newline=$'\n'
 do echo "${NEW_MOVIES_DIRLIST//$newline//}${LINKNAME}"
done

Comment: Move the `newline=$'\n'` to before the loop.  You should have got error messages with the code you used.